# SML Fibonacci large number . Using int datatype

Tags: sml

I want big int in SML. please let me know direction.

I can make normal fibonacci. but I have to print fibo(100) only using int not intinf.

```
fun fibo 0 = 0
  | fibo n =
    if n <= 2
    then 1
    else fibo (n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I have to print `fibo(100)`
> 2. only using *int*, not *IntInf.int*.

To address each of these,

1. Just printing (and not storing) `fibo(100)` does not necessarily involve finding a good representation for big numbers, so I would change this goal into "I have to find a way to represent big numbers so I can add them and display them."

   But, as John points out, overflowing *int* values is not your only concern when calculating `fibo(100)`. Just try your naive implementation for `fibo(40)` or so. It doesn't overflow, but it takes at least a few seconds on my computer. Now try `fibo(41)`, `fibo(42)`, etc. and witness the exponential growth. Your algorithm not only needs a representation of big integers, it also needs a sub-exponential resource usage.

   E.g. by making the function tail-recursive:

   ```
   fun fib n =
       let fun fib_ a b 0 = a (* or b *)
             | fib_ a b i = fib_ b (a+b) (i-1)
       in fib_ (Int.toLarge 0) (Int.toLarge 1) n end
   ```
2. You're essentially asking how to represent numbers that are bigger than *int*s using *int*s only, which, logically, is not possible. But perhaps you mean "by inventing a representation that uses multiple *int*s in series." That's exactly what *IntInf.int* does. See for example [How to use IntInf or LargeInt in SML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807441/how-to-use-intinf-or-largeint-in-sml).

   A naive imlementation of big integers could keep lists of *int*s, add them pairwise and carry over when `handle Overflow` is triggered. Or simply strings of digit characters! But it sounds more like a mental exercise than something useful.

Comment: I am actually want only using int type. There is no convert. 
for example. www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number.

Comment: You want big integers represented as regular integers, and you don't want an existing implementation that does this. So you must clearly implement big integers yourself. You could draw inspiration from [SML/NJ's IntInf library](https://github.com/xyproto/smlnj/blob/master/sml/system/smlnj/init/core-intinf.sml), which is about 600 lines of code. You could probably do with a lot less, since you only need addition and visualisation. The essential representation of big integers is arrays of values of fixed size.

Comment: You could point out that in this case, the tail recursive version isn't just a minor optimization but makes the difference between a feasible and an infeasible function. The naïve version requires an exponential number of function calls (unless you find a way to memoize the values, which I don't think SML does automatically).